# Convert time string expressed as <number>[m|h|d|s|w] to seconds in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a good method to convert a string representing time in the format of [m|h|d|s|w] (m= minutes, h=hours, d=days, s=seconds w=week) to number of seconds? I.e.

```
def convert_to_seconds(timeduration):
    ...

convert_to_seconds("1h")
-> 3600

convert_to_seconds("1d")
-> 86400
```

etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there is a good **simple** method that you can use in most languages *without having to read the manual for a datetime library*. This method can also be extrapolated to ounces/pounds/tons etc etc:

```
seconds_per_unit = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800}

def convert_to_seconds(s):
    return int(s[:-1]) * seconds_per_unit[s[-1]]
```

Comment: Haha, +1 and bravo, I'm embarrassed that this didn't occur to me!  I still recommend that everyone learn how to use the `datetime` library and the `timedelta` class for this kind of task, since in many cases it will be the most convenient option.  However, I must confess that your solution is a better one than mine for this particular question.

Comment: Yeah +1 this is quite a simple, elegant method for achieving what I wanted.. Thanks!

Comment: Would this work as expected if the time range spans a timezone change?

Answer (score 18):

I recommend using [the timedelta class](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) from the datetime module:

```
from datetime import timedelta

UNITS = {"s":"seconds", "m":"minutes", "h":"hours", "d":"days", "w":"weeks"}

def convert_to_seconds(s):
    count = int(s[:-1])
    unit = UNITS[ s[-1] ]
    td = timedelta(**{unit: count})
    return td.seconds + 60 * 60 * 24 * td.days
```

Internally, `timedelta` objects store everything as microseconds, seconds, and days.  So while you can give it parameters in units like milliseconds or months or years, in the end you'll have to take the `timedelta` you created and convert back to seconds.

In case the `**` syntax confuses you, it's the Python [apply](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply) syntax.  Basically, these function calls are all equivalent:

```
def f(x, y): pass

f(5, 6)
f(x=5, y=6)
f(y=6, x=5)

d = {"x": 5, "y": 6}
f(**d)
```

Comment: I swear I did not copy your answer ;-) +1 and I think I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 8):

And another to add to the mix.
This solution is brief, but fairly tolerant, and allows for multiples, such as `10m 30s`

```
from datetime import timedelta
import re

UNITS = {'s':'seconds', 'm':'minutes', 'h':'hours', 'd':'days', 'w':'weeks'}

def convert_to_seconds(text):
    return int(timedelta(**{
        UNITS.get(m.group('unit').lower(), 'seconds'): float(m.group('val'))
        for m in re.finditer(
            r'(?P<val>\d+(\.\d+)?)(?P<unit>[smhdw]?)',
            text.replace(' ', ''),
            flags=re.I
        )
    }).total_seconds())
```

Test results:

```
>>> convert_to_seconds('10s')
10
>>> convert_to_seconds('1')  # defaults to seconds
1
>>> convert_to_seconds('1m 10s')  # chaining
70
>>> convert_to_seconds('1M10S')  # case insensitive
70
>>> convert_to_seconds('1week 3days')  # ignores 'eek' and 'ays'
864000
>>> convert_to_seconds('This will take 1.25min, probably.')  # floats
75
```

not perfect

```
>>> convert_to_seconds('1 month 3 days')  # actually 1min 3days
259260
>>> convert_to_seconds('40s 10s')  # 1st value clobbered by 2nd
10
>>> convert_to_seconds('cook for 3 to 5 minutes')  # is not intelligent
303
```

Comment: Warning for future peeps. I used the above RegEx because (even after scanning it myself) I thought it was good. But CodeQL thankfully [flagged it](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/javascript/js-redos/#inefficient-regular-expression) because it "can" suffer from 2^n speed and if known by hackers, could allow a DDOS. if you remove the last `?` -> `(?P<val>\d+(\.\d+)?)(?P<unit>[smhdw])` which makes the unit optional, the efficiency is a lot better and removes any security scanning issues that may happen. Great answer BTW!

Answer (score 1):

I usually need to support raw numbers, string numbers ***and*** string numbers ending in [m|h|d|s|w].

This version will handle: 10, "10", "10s", "10m", "10h", "10d", "10w".

Hat tip to @Eli Courtwright's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3096934) on the string conversion.

```
UNITS = {"s":"seconds", "m":"minutes", "h":"hours", "d":"days", "w":"weeks"}

def convert_to_seconds(s):
    if isinstance(s, int):
        # We are dealing with a raw number
        return s

    try:
        seconds = int(s)
        # We are dealing with an integer string
        return seconds
    except ValueError:
        # We are dealing with some other string or type
        pass

    # Expecting a string ending in [m|h|d|s|w]
    count = int(s[:-1])
    unit = UNITS[ s[-1] ]
    td = timedelta(**{unit: count})
    return td.seconds + 60 * 60 * 24 * td.days
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Open source library MgntUtils in java (not php) that answers in part to this requirement. It contains a static method `parsingStringToTimeInterval(String value)` this method parses a string that is expected to hold some time interval value - a numeric value with optional time unit suffix. For example, string "38s" will be parsed as 38 seconds, "24m" - 24 minutes "4h" - 4 hours, "3d" - 3 days and "45" as 45 milliseconds. Supported suffixes are "s" for seconds, "m" for minutes, "h" for hours, and "d" for days. String without suffix is considered to hold a value in milliseconds. Suffixes are case insensitive. If provided String contains an unsupported suffix or holds negative numeric value or zero or holds a non-numeric value - then IllegalArgumentException is thrown. This method returns TimeInterval class - a class also defined in this library. Essentially, it holds two properties with relevant getters and setters: long "value" and java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit. But in addition to getters and setters this class has methods toMillis(), toSeconds(), toMinutes(), toHours() toDays(). Those methods return long vlaue in specified time scale (The same way as corresponding methods in class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

This method may be very useful for parsing time interval properties such as timeouts or waiting periods from configuration files. It eliminates unneeded calculations from different time scales to milliseconds back and forth. Consider that you have a methodInvokingInterval property that you need to set for 5 days. So in order to set the milliseconds value you will need to calculate that 5 days is 432000000 milliseconds (obviously not an impossible task but annoying and error prone) and then anyone else who sees the value 432000000 will have to calculate it back to 5 days which is frustrating. But using this method you will have a property value set to "5d" and invoking the code

```
long seconds = TextUtils.parsingStringToTimeInterval("5d").toSeconds();
```

will solve your conversion problem. Obviously, this is not overly complex feature, but it could add simplicity and clarity in your configuration files and save some frustration and "stupid" miscalculation into milliseconds bugs. Here is the link to the article that describes the MgntUtils library as well as where to get it: [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)