# How to convert an H:MM:SS time string to seconds in Python?

Tags: python

Basically I have the inverse of this problem: [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

I have a string in the format H:MM:SS (always 2 digits for minutes and seconds), and I need the integer number of seconds that it represents. How can I do this in python?

For example:

- "1:23:45" would produce an output of 5025
- "0:04:15" would produce an output of 255
- "0:00:25" would produce an output of 25

etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert time string expressed as <number>\[m|h|d|s|w\] to seconds in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096860/convert-time-string-expressed-as-numbermhdsw-to-seconds-in-python)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```python
def get_sec(time_str):
    """Get seconds from time."""
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)


print(get_sec('1:23:45'))
print(get_sec('0:04:15'))
print(get_sec('0:00:25'))
```

Comment: It's very nice and clear and compact but fails if the time does not have all the components, e.g. '3' or "1:21", or if the seconds part is a float. For these cases maybe the tzot solution below could be better fit, using float values

Answer (score 68):

```
ts = '1:23:45'
secs = sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(ts.split(':'))))
print(secs)
```

Comment: That's a really interesting technique. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: What does that double-star operator do?

Comment: @hughes Exponentiation.

Comment: This superior code will also handle `s` and `m:s` strings like "53" and "2:41" correctly

Comment: This is great. Change `int(x)` to `float(x)` and it'll handle decimal seconds, plus it doesn't need a leading zero for hour. VTT timestamps omit the leading 0 hour until hour > 1.

Answer (score 16):

Using datetime module

```
import datetime
t = '10:15:30'
h,m,s = t.split(':')
print(int(datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h),minutes=int(m),seconds=int(s)).total_seconds()))
```

Output: 36930

Comment: What does the output from your code look like given the OP's example input?

Comment: You don't need `re` for this. Strings have a split method: `str.split()`. Much cleaner to just use `t.split(':')` instead of `re.split(':', t)`.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, as it seemed to be the most standard way of doing it. I slightly altered the conversion of h,m,s to int using a comprehension list to make the conversion line cleaner, which ends up looking like this: `h, m, s = [int(x) for x in t.split(':')]`.

Answer (score 13):

Without many checks, and assuming it's either "SS" or "MM:SS" or "HH:MM:SS" (although not necessarily two digits per part):

```
def to_seconds(timestr):
    seconds= 0
    for part in timestr.split(':'):
        seconds= seconds*60 + int(part, 10)
    return seconds

>>> to_seconds('09')
9
>>> to_seconds('2:09')
129
>>> to_seconds('1:02:09')
3729
```

This is a different “spelling” of FMc's answer :)

Comment: Really useful. Thanks. I like that you take into account for shorter strings that only contain seconds or minutes... 

Comment: This is the best solution here. How come it's so under-voted!? It considers strings with missing `minutes` or `hours` part in a neat, single function, and without using any extra library. Kudos!

Answer (score 6):

Using `datetime` module is also posible and more robust

```
import datetime as dt

def get_total_seconds(stringHMS):
   timedeltaObj = dt.datetime.strptime(stringHMS, "%H:%M:%S") - dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
   return timedeltaObj.total_seconds()
```

`datetime.strptime` parses the string according to format %H:%M:%S, and it creates a datetime object as year 1900, month1, day 1, hour H, minute M, and second S.

That's why to get the total of seconds is necessary to subtract the year, month and day.

```
print(get_total_seconds('1:23:45'))
>>> 5025.0

print(get_total_seconds('0:04:15'))
>>> 255.0

print(get_total_seconds('0:00:25'))
>>>25.0
```

Comment: This worked for me. I used "%H:%M:%S.%f" instead to handle decimal seconds

Answer (score 4):

For %H:%M:%S.%f

```
def get_sec(time_str):
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lambda and reduce a list and the fact that m=60s and h=60m. (see "Reducing a List" at http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)

```
timestamp = "1:23:45"
seconds = reduce(lambda x, y: x*60+y, [int(i) for i in (timestamp.replace(':',',')).split(',')])
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really like any of the given answers, so I used the following:

```python
def timestamp_to_seconds(t):
    return sum(float(n) * m for n,
               m in zip(reversed(time.split(':')), (1, 60, 3600))
               )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the time into a list and add each individual time component, multiplying the hours component by 3600 (the number of seconds in an hour) and the minutes component by 60 (number of seconds in a minute), like:

```
timeInterval ='00:35:01'
list = timeInterval.split(':')
hours = list[0]
minutes = list[1]
seconds = list[2]
total = (int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds))
print("total = ", total)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parts = time_string.split(":")
seconds = int(parts[0])*(60*60) + int(parts[1])*60 + int(parts[2])
```

Comment: Almost worked, I had to use int(...) as taskinoor suggested for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @FMc's solution which embodies half of [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Advantage of Horner's method: Skip reversing the list, avoid [power](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) calculation.

```
from functools import reduce

timestamp = "1:23:45"
seconds = reduce(lambda s, d: s * 60 + int(d), timestamp.split(":"), 0)
```

or, if you dislike [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) ([as does Guido van Rossum](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196#:%7E:text=So%20now%20reduce().%20This%20is%20actually%20the%20one%20I%27ve%20always%20hated%20most) and @0xc0de [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402812/how-to-convert-an-hmmss-time-string-to-seconds-in-python#comment125232000_57610198)):

```
timestamp = "1:23:45"
seconds = 0
for d in timestamp.split(":"):
    seconds = seconds * 60 + int(d)
```

If you prefer [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (as does @nathan-rice [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971056)):

```
from itertools import accumulate, repeat
from operator import mul

def timestamp_to_seconds(t):
    return sum(int(n) * m for n, m in
       zip(reversed(t.split(":")), accumulate(repeat(60), func=mul, initial=1)))
```

Comment: Goes a step forward in performance, but maybe a step backwards in readability, unless all your co-workers/fellow code readers are good with `reduced` readability. +1 for those cases, I am not a fan of reduce() though and would prefer to avoid these.

Answer (score 1):

I liked tzot's answer above the best for my purposes because my H:M:S are human created and the can have float seconds part
Here is my small modification

```
def hms_to_seconds(timestr:str)->float:
    """Get seconds from time.

    :param timestr: hh:mm:ss.xxx string or mm:s.xxx or simply s.xxx where xxx is the fraction of seconds
    :returns: time in float seconds
    """
    seconds= 0.
    for part in timestr.split(':'):
        seconds= seconds*60. + float(part)
    return seconds

>>> hms_to_seconds('3.00')
3.0
>>> hms_to_seconds('1:3.00')
63.0
>>> hms_to_seconds('1:0:3.5')
3603.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you have days on string:

```
def duration2sec(string):
    if "days" in string:
        days = string.split()[0]
        hours = string.split()[2].split(':')
        return int(days) * 86400 + int(hours[0]) * 3600 + int(hours[1]) * 60 + int(hours[2])
    else:
        hours = string.split(':')
        return int(hours[0]) * 3600 + int(hours[1]) * 60 + int(hours[2])
```

Comment: The question asks for converting H:MM:SS time string to seconds not to convert days to to secs. Please have try to reword your answer for the question

Comment: The example is functional, `else` part will do that. But I agree that the simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple generalization to the great response of [taskinoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377953/taskinoor)

In the context of my problem the format is similar, but includes AM or PM.

Format 'HH:MM:SS AM' or 'HH:MM:SS PM'

For this case the function changes to:

```
def get_sec(time_str):
"""Get Seconds from time."""
if 'AM' in time_str:
    time_str = time_str.strip('AM')
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    seconds = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
if 'PM' in time_str:
    time_str = time_str.strip('PM')
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    seconds = (12 + int(h)) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

return seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas using @JayRizzo 's cool function and a list comprehension:

```py
def get_sec(time_str):
    """Get Seconds from time."""
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

df['secs']=[get_sec(x) for x in df['original_time_string']]
```