# Convert possibly incorrect time to seconds

Tags: python, time

Having such string `12:65:84` and told that it represents time in `h:m:s` AND
values there can be not correct, e.g. `65` minutes that should be translated to `1` hour and `5` minutes

I need to reduce these numbers to total amount of seconds.

Naive solution will be:

```
time_string = '12:65:84'
hours, minutes, seconds = [int(i) for i in time_string.split(':')
total_seconds = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds
```

Question: How it can be done better, ideally without using any import, maybe with some combination of `map`, `reduce` and their friends?

Comment: Any datetime module you get will parse the time string and throws error for incorrect values.  Your algorithm works, what's the problem?

Comment: @Trimax, no problems here, just question: "how to do better?". Maybe with `reduce` or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an H:MM:SS time string to seconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402812/how-to-convert-an-hmmss-time-string-to-seconds-in-python)

Comment: *"12:65:84"* time in `h:m:s` - what am I missing here? 65 minutes? Please @micgeronimo explain?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov, yes values there can be invalid, if it was valid I'd just used `strptime`

Comment: Ok, @micgeronimo. 10x for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `timedelta` for the same as:

```
s='12:65:84'
h,m,s=[int(i) for i in s.split(':')]
t=timedelta(hours=h, seconds=s, minutes=m)
res=t.total_seconds()
```