# How to convert date to unix format

Tags: python, date

How to convert below date to unix format using python ?

I have checked for date month and year format but it is not working

Date: "10 Nov 2017"

Please help.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: madprops@ 01/12/2011 this is different format than "10 Nov 2017" when i used code on this format it gives me an error:
ValueError: time data '10 Nov 2017' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: Yeah you need a different format. Check the docs I linked to suit it to your date format, check the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

You can use %b for Locale’s abbreviated month name.

Try this:

```
import time
import datetime
s = "10 Nov 2017"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y").timetuple())
```

Comment: Thanks.. what if i have to convert "01:53:52" to unix ?

Comment: s = "10 Nov 2017 01:53:52"
print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple()))

Comment: but it is not working if I only needed "01:53:52" but not "10 Nov 2017"

Comment: I have used 
s = "01:53:52"
print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S").timetuple()))
but it gives me: OverflowError: mktime argument out of range

Comment: This is different question. But you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402812/how-to-convert-an-hmmss-time-string-to-seconds-in-python

Comment: How to convert "01/30/2003 02:00 AM" to unix ? Please help

Comment: Refer the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html. Read it first fully and then come back if you have any issue

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be solved as follows

```
import time
import datetime
s = "01/dec/2011"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%b/%Y").timetuple())
output:
1322697600.0
```

Comment: varnit@ in my case date is "10 Nov 2017", if it would have been like "01/12/2011" then the code worked

Comment: i have edited the question you just have to use %b to use months name hope it helps

Comment: for complete documentation of strptime documentation you can refer to this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: If that solved your problem mark it as solved and upvote it thanks in advance