# Convert time command output to seconds

Tags: python, time, python-3.8

I have a script which outputs the time taken by a command as follows:

```
real    112m5.559s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I am parsing the output from the script using python. I want to represent the real time in seconds format. I have the parsed output in a variable `real_time`.

Here's how I am currently converting it to seconds format.

```
def gettime(x):
    m,s = map(float,x[:-1].split('m'))
    return 60 * m + s

real_time = "112m5.559s"
gettime(real_time)
```

Is there any other way to do this? (Probably a one liner which is more efficient)

---

`timeit` tests for the answers given below :

```
import pandas as pd

def gettime(x):
    m,s = map(float,x[:-1].split('m'))
    return 60 * m + s

real_time = "112m5.559s"

%timeit gettime(real_time)
%timeit int(real_time.split("m")[0]) * 60 + float(real_time.split("m")[1][:-1])
%timeit pd.to_timedelta(real_time).total_seconds()
%timeit sum(float(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(real_time[:-1].split('m'))))
```

Output

```
1.27 µs ± 55.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.39 µs ± 104 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
15.8 µs ± 714 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.63 µs ± 446 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Current method seems to be the efficient one. [@bigbounty's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6849682/bigbounty) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63007982/10155936) comes close to being both efficient and one-liner.

Comment: Can we ask that script to give it in seconds directly?

Comment: @Aditya Since I am using `time` command, it is possible to do so I believe with `TIMEFORMAT` env variable but at the cost of losing user and sys time info

Answer (score 1):

```
In [86]: int(real_time.split("m")[0]) * 60 + float(real_time.split("m")[1][:-1])
Out[86]: 6725.559
```

Comment: One-liner and almost efficient as the current method I am using

Comment: If you go ahead with pandas to_delta, you will have to import pandas library just for this purpose. Think of tradeoffs

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pandas.to_timedelta()` to directly parse the string, e.g.

```
pd.to_timedelta('112m5.559s').total_seconds()
Out[26]: 6725.559
```

However, your string splitting method seems more than 10x faster:

```
%timeit gettime('112m5.559s')
1.04 µs ± 18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit pd.to_timedelta('112m5.559s').total_seconds()
11.8 µs ± 214 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

...so I would stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer for a similar question:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6402934/10535841

As for the solution, using the technique used above,

```py
real_time = '112m5.559s'
secs = sum(float(x) * 60 ** i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(real_time[:-1].split('m'))))
print(secs)
```

Comment: according to a quick `%timeit`, this is only about half as efficient as the OP's solution

Comment: True, this isn't faster than the actual one