# converting a muti-time formatted string into seconds (pandas)

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I've been searching for a solution to this and the closest I got was here:
[Convert time string expressed as <number>[m|h|d|s|w] to seconds in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096860/convert-time-string-expressed-as-numbermhdsw-to-seconds-in-python)

however none of the solutions work because the time format only sometimes contains one unit and is inconsistant throughout the column. e.g.

`['4h 30m 24s', '13w 5d', '11w']`

when I `.apply()` this over the entire column it fails. How can I convert all of these rows into seconds? I tried `df['time_value'].str.split()` but this is a very messy and seemingly inefficient way to do this, there must be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `apply`ing this method?

```
def convert_to_seconds(s):
    seconds = 0
    seconds_per_unit = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800}
    for part in s.split():
        number = int(part[:-1])
        unit = part[-1]
        seconds += number * seconds_per_unit[unit]
    return seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `stack` then with `map` mapping those to second

```
s=pd.Series(l)
s=s.str.split(expand=True).stack().to_frame('ALL')
s['v']=s['ALL'].str[:-1].astype(int)
s['t']=s['ALL'].str[-1]
seconds_per_unit = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800}
(s.t.map(seconds_per_unit)*s.v).unstack()
Out[625]: 
           0         1     2
0    14400.0    1800.0  24.0
1  7862400.0  432000.0   NaN
2  6652800.0       NaN   NaN
```