# sort a list of string and number base on both with specific order

Tags: python, list, sorting, mixed

I'm looking for the best practice of sorting my_list like my_ordered_list.

```
my_list = ['1h-data', '1m-data', '15m-data' , '4h-data', '50s-data']
my_ordered_list = ['50s-data', '1m-data', '15m-data', '1h-data', '4h-data']
```

I can define my_specific list for string part like:
`['s', 'm' , 'h']`
and then sort two times first by string part and second by integer part and finally join them, but there must be a better one.

Comment: Related: [Convert time string expressed as <number>m|h|d|s|w to seconds in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096860/convert-time-string-expressed-as-numbermhdsw-to-seconds-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way with `index`:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (['s', 'm', 'h'].index(x.split('-')[0][-1]), int(x.split('-')[0][:-1])))
['50s-data', '1m-data', '15m-data', '1h-data', '4h-data']
>>>
```

### Or with python version >= Python 3.8, you could use the walrus operator:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (['s', 'm', 'h'].index((t:=x.split('-')[0])[-1]), int(t[:-1])))
['50s-data', '1m-data', '15m-data', '1h-data', '4h-data']
>>>
```

**Edit:**

If you have stuff like `80s`, try:

```
my_list = ['1h-data', '1m-data', '15m-data' , '4h-data', '80s-data']
dct = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600}
def func(x):
    a = x.split('-')[0]
    return int(a[:-1]) * dct.get(a[-1])
print(sorted(my_list, key=func))
```

Output:

```
['1m-data', '80s-data', '15m-data', '1h-data', '4h-data']
```

Comment: You could use the [`:=` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), to avoid calling `.split('-')` twice: `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (['s', 'm', 'h'].index((t:=x.split('-')[0])[-1]), int(t[:-1])))`

Comment: Also please note that this line of code won't convert between minutes and hours and seconds, so for instance the list `['80s-data', '1m-data']` would be sorted incorrectly

Comment: Which you could fix by replacing the list of time units by a dict mapping time units to a number of seconds: `time_units={'s': 1, 'm': 60, 'h': 3600}` then `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: time_units[(t:=x.split('-')[0])[-1]] * int(t[:-1]))
`

Comment: Or use any of the suggestions at [Convert time string expressed as <number>m|h|d|s|w to seconds in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096860/convert-time-string-expressed-as-numbermhdsw-to-seconds-in-python) to implement `convert_to_seconds` separately, then simply `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: convert_to_seconds(x.split('-')[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` to handle the numbers/strings

```
import re

lookup = {'h': 3600, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
my_list = ['1h-data', '1m-data', '15m-data', '4h-data', '50s-data']
temp = [x.split('-')[0] for x in my_list]
temp = [(int(re.findall(r"(\d+)", x)[0]), re.findall(r"(\D+)", x)[0]) for x in temp]
temp = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: x[0] * lookup[x[1]])
ordered_list = [f'{x[0]}{x[1]}-data' for x in temp]
print(ordered_list)
```

output

```
['50s-data', '1m-data', '15m-data', '1h-data', '4h-data']
```